# Grails: how to perform action when a Domain Class property is set in GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, setter, interceptor

Is there any way to make a Domain Class setter have imperative actions. This is what I wish would work, is it possible some other way?

Domain Class:

```
Class ExampleDomain {
  BigDecimal someNumber
  def setSomeNumber = {setVal ->
    println "Today is a good day to be the number: ${setVal}"
  }

}
```

Can I only bind events on `onUpdate` and things like that or is there a way to have changes to the Java object drive events?

For example:

```
def thisThing = new ExampleDomain(someNumber:3.0) //prints "Today is a good day to be the number: 3.0"
thisThing.someNumber = 5.8  //prints "Today is a good day to be the number: 5.8"
thisThing.save()  //prints nothing
```

Is that possible behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining getter/setter methods instead of closures:

```
Class ExampleDomain {
  BigDecimal someNumber

  void setSomeNumber(someNumber) {
    println "Today is a good day to be the number: ${someNumber}"
    this.someNumber = someNumber
  }

  BigDecimal getSomeNumber() {
    someNumber
  }
}
```

works for

```
//prints "Today is a good day to be the number: 5.8"
new ExampleDomain().someNumber = 5.8
```

Comment: As a note: if you aren't doing anything dynamic in, for example, the getter (`getSomeNumber()`), you can simply not include it.  Groovy [automatically creates the setter and getter](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans), so you are basically overriding the default implementation.